# Parameter DTD for dynamic XML?

Tags: xml, dtd

Maybe this is some task for XML and DTD gurus? Hope you can help me out of my dark.

my XML file needs either this DTD entity

```
  <!-- testing -->
  &test-commonTestingLibs;
```

or this

```
  <!-- testing -->
  &compile-commonTestingLibs;
```

my DTD for is looks like this for the **test-***

```
<!ENTITY test-commonTestingLibs "
  <dependency org='org.dbunit' name='dbunit' rev='${lib.version.dbunit}' conf='test->default, sources, javadoc' />

  <dependency org='org.testng' name='testng' rev='${lib.version.testng}' conf='test->default, sources, javadoc' />
" >
```

or  for the **compile-***

```
<!ENTITY compile-commonTestingLibs "
  <dependency org='org.dbunit' name='dbunit' rev='${lib.version.dbunit}' conf='compile->default, sources, javadoc' />

  <dependency org='org.testng' name='testng' rev='${lib.version.testng}' conf='compile->default, sources, javadoc' />
" >
```

Is it possible to define a DTD which makes the identical code more reusable with a parameter "**aParameter**"?

```
<!ENTITY commonTestingLibs-%%aParameter%% "
  <dependency org='org.dbunit' name='dbunit' rev='${lib.version.dbunit}' conf='%%aParameter%%->default, sources, javadoc' />

  <dependency org='org.testng' name='testng' rev='${lib.version.testng}' conf='%%aParameter%%->default, sources, javadoc' />
" >
```

so I could either do a entity definition with the aParameter in the DTD or in the XML as a param?

This would help me to eliminiate redundant definitions, which often are not so short as the example above and the difference is exactly only one simple keyword "**aParameter**" (mostly: compile, test, provided, ...)

Comment: What is the context? Are you using Maven or some stuff like that?

Comment: potame, I am using IVY but it should be independent of ivy/maven. Since this questions is related to dtd-entites.
of course if I can solve it in ivy, it would also be fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a [parameter entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-PE) to reference the small piece that changes. It's very similar to your suggestion, but instead of trying to also change the entity name, you'd have a generic entity and only the data inside would change.

```
<!-- Change this to "compile" when needed. -->
<!ENTITY % type "test">

<!-- Make this entity generic, so you don't have to change which reference you're using. -->
<!ENTITY commonTestingLibs "
  <dependency org='org.dbunit' name='dbunit' rev='${lib.version.dbunit}' conf='%type;->default, sources, javadoc' />
  <dependency org='org.testng' name='testng' rev='${lib.version.testng}' conf='%type;->default, sources, javadoc' />
">
```

What I would do to make switching from "test" to "compile" easier is to use [conditional (IGNORE/INCLUDE) sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-condition-sect). This way you can put all of the declarations specific to that type in one place and then, in a sense, turn them off and on.

This would make it much easier to extend because to change types, you only have to change one place in the DTD.

In the example below, anything inside of `<![%test;[ ... ]]>` will be included and anything inside of `<![%compile;[ ... ]]>` will be ignored...

```
<!ENTITY % test "INCLUDE">
<!ENTITY % compile "IGNORE">

<![%test;[ 
<!ENTITY % type "test">
<!-- Any other "test" specific declarations. -->
]]>

<![%compile;[ 
<!ENTITY % type "compile">
<!-- Any other "compile" specific declarations. -->
]]>

<!ENTITY commonTestingLibs "
  <dependency org='org.dbunit' name='dbunit' rev='${lib.version.dbunit}' conf='%type;->default, sources, javadoc' />
  <dependency org='org.testng' name='testng' rev='${lib.version.testng}' conf='%type;->default, sources, javadoc' />
">
```

To ignore "test" and include "compile", you only need to change two entities:

```
<!ENTITY % test "IGNORE">
<!ENTITY % compile "INCLUDE">
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, took me some time to understand your both approaches. My issue is I need the definitions of compile and test in one DTD file.
Means, I am searching for an option of how I can define something like this: 

    <!ENTITY commonTestingLibs "
       <dependency org='org.testng' name='testng' rev='${lib.version.testng}' conf='%type;->default, sources, javadoc' />
">

once for compile for test and other "configurations" like runtime, provided and so on. So I need more a include feature with a variable/parameter